# Returning XML data parsed via jQuery

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery, xml-parsing, scope

What I was doing is read an XML file and get the data via jQuery into my HTML file.

As I have found in many tutorials I am using jQuery's `.get()` method. It serves me well except for one problem!

**This is the XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<books>
  <book title="CSS Mastery" imageurl="images/css.jpg">
    <description>
      info goes here.
    </description>
  </book>

  <book title="Professional ASP.NET" imageurl="images/asp.jpg">
    <description>
      info goes here.
    </description>
  </book>

  <book title="Learning jQuery" imageurl="images/lj.jpg">
    <description>
      info goes here.
    </description>
  </book>
</books>
```

**Here is my HTML file with jQuery codes:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
      $("document").ready(function() {
        $.get("one.xml", function(d) {
          var title = [];
          var description = [];

          $(d).find("book").each(function() {
            title.push($(this).attr("title"));
            description.push($(this).find("description").text());
          });

          console.log(title);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    // BODY contents...
  </body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is I want the titles and descriptions to be returned so that i can use these arrays inside other functions. According to the jQuery code my `title` array is being printed in the `console` now but when I try to print the `title` array outside of the `.get()` method it says `"title is undefined"`.

I have tried returning the arrays at the end of the function but no luck. I'm not sure if I have made my questions clear or not so I paste the code thats giving me the error below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("document").ready(function() {
        $.get("one.xml", function(d){
          var title = [];
          var description = [];

          $(d).find("book").each(function() {
            title.push($(this).attr("title"));
            description.push($(this).find("description").text());
          });
        });

        console.log(title);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    // BODY contents...
  </body>
</html>
```

In this block of code it is saying `"title isn't defined` and notice I am consoling the `title` array outside of the `.get()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of variable scope, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope). If you want to use title & description in any other function of javascript then you can directly call that javascript function immediate after saving title & description(inside callback function of `$.get`) like follows.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$.get("one.xml", function(d){
    var title       = [];
    var description = [];
    $(d).find("book").each(function(){
        title.push($(this).attr("title"));
        description.push($(this).find("description").text());
    });
    call_to_your_function_with_title_and_desc(title, description)
});
```

Comment: I have thought of this before but i was just curious that if there's any other way around. I am fairly new to jquery anyways i appreciate your help! thumbs up!

Comment: @FoysalAhmed - I understand your curiosity to learn jQuery but I always prefer that you search over questions already asked, if you dont found answer of your question then create new question... anyway best of luck...!

Comment: I have searched through google and stackoverflow but I didn't find anyone to use it in such way. all i have seen is most of the tutorials and solutions are about printing the recieved data from the xml file in the document. that's why i had to post the problem. and i thought there might be some way to do get the data returned outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

just use like below :

```
title = [];
description = [];
```

If you dont use `var` before variable name it will be in global scope, so you can use those two variables inside other functions as well.

Comment: @Tonu Bhai, It'll work but it's a very bad practice :(

BTW, `console.log` still won't work because it'll execute before the callback push data to that array.

Comment: bad or good practice can be defined on situations :)
in that case he have to use callback method within that scope.

Comment: Again he can use __jQuery.deferred__ to use an additional callback with the .get()'s callback.

Comment: I have tried declaring the variables without var keywords but nothing changed. 
Im not being impatient or something but i can't resist asking "so there's no way of getting that variable out of that function?"